# CSS: Scale font a constant factor

Tags: css

I work on a website that uses a font which does not support a new language that we have to support for the website. (A couple of letters are missing)

An easy fix was to exchange the font that we currently use (Neuton) to just "serif" for that language, which at least gives us a complete set of characters for the new language.

Unfortunately, the font is much larger than Neuton was before, even though font-size stayed the same everywhere. It is impossible to change hundreds of "font-size" directives - is there a way to scale the font in general in "font-family"?

Comment: Not with font family, if your fonts are defined with a relative size then you could possibly change all of them by changing the body font size for that new lang

Comment: If you could provide some texts and the exact fonts, that would be nice. Now all we can do is suggest "try this" and "try that". Have you tried the `font-size-adjust` property? Or maybe you could do something with the `unicode-range` descriptor in the `@font-face` rule.

Comment: font-size-adjust is looking good, please create an answer